# Fazer com CSS fundo em degradê na tela toda

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte `css`:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgb(172,204,193) 20%, rgb(40, 22, 111));
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

que me dá o seguinte efeito de fundo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O *objetivo* é fazer com `CSS` fundo em **degradê** na **tela** toda e não apenas na área que tem conteúdo.

Como fazer isso?

A ideia é fazer um `margin-bottom: 0` naquela `div` preta no final mas não é possível por causa doe feito gradiente!

Percebam ainda que por causa do efeito degradê em circulo, foi necessário limitar o `html` a `100%` e isso impede a ultima div de chegar no final do browser.

Comment: Porque não colocar os elementos que estão na frente transparentes?

Comment: Está ok seu css, acho que falta um `body, html { height: 100% }` só.

Comment: Carlos se a resposta indicada como Duplicada não resolver me fala que eu retiro o voto.

Comment: Oi. Não! Não resolveu, acrescentei mais detalhes do CSS  na pergunta. Segue o link: http://wesleyanagceu.com.br/

Comment: Carlos vc só colocou height 100% no body. Tem que por height 100% no html tbm, tem que ser nos 2 pra funcionar. Coloca 100% no html que vai funcionar

Comment: oi, só para contribuir mesmo, html {  height: 100vh; }. também funcionou. Não foi preciso adicionar o heigth ao body não, Muito obrigado. Caso quera postar uma resposta eu a aceitarei.

Comment: Hum, mas o .final { margin-bottom: 20px; NÃO funcionou. Ou seja, não consegui chegar a última div no final da página